# roscore warning

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

when I want to run roscore i see a message like this in terminal:

> WARNING: disk usage in log directory
> [/home/mohammad/.ros/log] is over 1GB.
> It's recommended that you use the
> 'rosclean' command.

Of course i have no problem with running master and it works fine. Should i do something necessary for not seeing again this message?

thanks:))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195630/roscore-warning/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-10-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-10-22**:
Have you tried using rosclean as the message suggests?

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-10-22**:
yes of course. But it did not effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you run `rosclean purge` ?

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on 2014-10-23**:
yes thanks it works:))

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-23**:
@mohammad please accept the answer at the left to give @ROSCMBOT credit and so others know your answer is solved.

**Comment by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on 2022-08-01**:
You can use rosclean purge to clean it .

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-01**:
Please do not post the answer which is posted already.